# When to use StringIndexer vs StringIndexer+OneHotEncoder?

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

When / in what context should you use StringIndexer vs StringIndexer+OneHotEncoder?

Looking at the docs for sparkml's StringIndexer (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features#stringindexer) and OneHotEncoder (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features#onehotencoder), it's not obvious to me when to use just StringIndexer vs StringIndexer+OneHotEncoder (I've been using just a StringIndexer on a benchmarking dataset and getting pretty good results as is, but I suppose that does not mean that doing this is necessarily "correct"). The ohe docs refer to a StringIndexer > OneHotEncoder > VectorAssembler staging pipeline, but the way it is worded make that seem optional (vs just doing StringIndexer > VectorAssembler).

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 2):

First, it is necessary to use StringIndexer before OneHotEncoder, because [OneHotEncoder](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/ml/feature/OneHotEncoder.html) needs a column of category indices as input.

To answer your question, StringIndexer may bias some machine learning models. For instance, after passing a data frame with a categorical column that has three classes (0, 1, and 2) to a linear regression model. A relationship of double between value 1 and 2 may be concluded while it is just a different class, a different index. When having a vector with zeros and ones at specific positions can transmit the desired information of class difference. So finally, it depends on the model used during training, tree-based models are sensitive to one-hot encoding and become worse with one-hot encoded vectors.

You may consider reading [Create a Pipeline - Learning Spark](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-spark-2nd/9781492050032/ch10.html#creating_a_pipeline) for more details behind one hot encoding.